# How to initiate a Listener which can accept two events in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML

```
<div id="69" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
   <div class="prd-items-detials">
      <ul>
         <li class="head">
            <form> <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclas" name="checkbox-mini-0" id="69" data-mini="true" id_attr="69"><label item_id_itr_some="69" class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">Cold Tea, Fresh Chai gold Ice </label><i class="delete-item-btn"></i>
            </form>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div style="display:none;" class="Topping-details" id="69">
   </div>
</div>
```

Right now i got a event listener when clicked on a checkbox as shown below

```
$(document).on("click", ".activateUiHTML .checkboxclas", function(e) { 

});
```

My requirement is that i need the same action to be iniated when clicked div under the `activateUiHTML form` also .

So is it possible to modify the above function to accpet both ??

How to initiate  a Listener which can accept two events in Jquery ??

Answer (score 4):

Remember that jQuery's selectors are CSS selectors, and in CSS you can use the comma to apply rules to a [group of selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping):

```
$(document).on("click", ".activateUiHTML .checkboxclas, .activateUiHTML form", function(e) { 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$(document).on("click", ".activateUiHTML .checkboxclas, .activateUiHTML form", function(e) { 

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kTjar/)